# Create multiple profiles for Firefox Portable on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox, firefox-profile

I am using a Firefox Portable version, and I am wondering how can I create multiple profiles?

I used `pathToFirefoxPortable.exe -CreateProfile profile`, which starts Firefox, but I don't think it created a profile for me. This approach however works on normal non-portable editions of Firefox, but not on portable ones. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Firefox portable only has one profile. Though you can copy the profile folder in `FirefoxPortable\data\profile` to `FirefoxPortable\data\profile2` for example. You can then make changes to this file `FirefoxPortable\Other\Source\FirefoxPortable.ini` as such:

```
ProfileDirectory=Data\profile2
```

*[Firefox Multiple Profiles: the easy way](http://portableapps.com/node/14965)* describes a way of automating this.