# UI way to have two Firefox profiles?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am required to access some pages on Firefox via a proxy for work, and I would rather not have most of my browsing pass through that proxy.

My solution is to always start Firefox from the terminal. With `firefox -p --no-remote`, and then I can select the normal profile, or the work profile (which has a distinct theme and proxy set).

Now I have to set up the same thing for someone else using [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) that is not too familiar with the terminal. My first idea was to create two launcher icons on Ubuntu with `firefox --no-remote -p A` and another with `-p B`. But that is annoying in that now the launcher makes changing applications by clicking the icon always launch a new window.

Is there a way for Ubuntu to have the Firefox icon for the Main profile, and when clicked move the focus to that window, and maybe a new icon that launches the specialize profile?

Or is there any UI in Firefox itself?

(Please, do not suggest extensions to change the proxy, as this is what I am trying to move away from, mostly because the user always forgets the extension on. The profile can change the theme to make human errors harder to happen.)

Comment: I'm wondering if you can acheive this with a portable version. https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./  Also check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/1110227/create-multiple-profiles-for-firefox-portable-on-windows-10/1110261

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  Whatever launches Firefox (doesn't have to be a terminal command), can include the -p.  You get a pop-up where you select the profile you want.  If you don't want that selection step, you can use two shortcuts, one for each profile.  You launch the one you want.  I'm not understand the third option you're looking for.

Comment: @fixer1234 i describe the exact "two launchers" solution you mention on the 3rd paragraph. Now you can't change windows using the mouse or alt-tab on ubuntu's dumbed down window manager.

Comment: The question describes a problem of selecting from several profiles to pick what to launch.  The comment describes a problem of how to launch multiple concurrent Firefox instances (with different profiles), or maybe having launched multiple concurrent instances, how to switch between them with a mouse or keyboard shortcut.  So it still isn't clear exactly what problem you're trying to solve.  This might be easier to follow if you describe the entire scenario you would like to accomplish, and what part of that isn't cooperating.  Or I might just be dense and this makes perfect sense to others.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for the interest. i start saying that launching a profile is a solved problem, somewhat, with `-p`. but then, i proceed to explain (3rd paragraph) how that is a problem on *ubuntu* (that's why the tags are firefox and ubuntu) and there the problem is exactly about the launcher. not much about firefox, though firefox might have a feature that works around the problem.